# What is a profiler measuring and how is that different from TTFB?

Tags: php, magento

I am using the magento profiler and it gives a reading of how long it took for the PHP code to run, I think.

What I have found that the TTFB - time to first byte value is much higher (sometimes double) than the profiler time.

What else is forming part of the TTFB value?

Here is the profiler time below:

[image: Example of profiler value]

Here is the TTFB for the same request:

[image]

Comment: Network latency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The profiler is not including the `magento/lib` code execution.

You should use a PHP debugger instead of the magento one.